# Android notification always return me previous bundle data

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, bundle

I am trying to get new data on every push notification i receive,
I am passing new data with every new push notification then add this data into bundle and pass it to my activity,
The issue every time when i send push notification my activity always use previous data in bundle.

Here is my code,

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Myactivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("post_id", newsletter_key);
        b.putString("newsletter_title", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("bundle_push", b);

        //notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", newsletter_key.toString());

        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       // notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity



        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


                notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Any help ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you getting the `newsletter_key` and `message`.

Comment: try `PendingIntent intent= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` [FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

Comment: i am using this code to get bundle data
Bundle push = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle_push");
        if(push!=null) {

            fisco_id = push.getString("post_id");
            fisco_title = push.getString("newsletter_title");

        }

Comment: @Dahaval thank you you safe my day,
how can i accept your answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace PendingIntent by below Code

```
PendingIntent intent= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

reference - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html